# Recover git repo from a backup that has not backed up .git folder

Tags: git

I am new to git and using it rather carefully for my own work and collaborations with some colleagues.

I had to completely re-install my computer. As short-term backup, I using a sort of google drive service (which sync all my folders in real-time). Unfortunately this service have not saved the .git folder, so my repo aren't a git repo right now but they are for sure up to date.

What is the right and clean way to recover a proper git repository?

Thanks a lot for your help

p.s I've tried two solutions found on the web: 
1) I ran: git init
          git remote add origin "myremoteURI"
          git pull origin master
Output:   that command will overwrite all files in my local folder (which I don't want since I have maybe some more recent change). Could I run a git add  " this file list" + git commit ?
2) I tried: git clone "myRepoURI" in a dummy folder
            copy .git folder from the dummy folder to my local repo
Output: seems to work but I'm clearly unsure. So prefer asking....

Comment: Things you need to do is, clone the repo in a dummy folder. And than copy paste your backup files in the cloned dummy folder. So your latest work from your local will detected as change against the repo.

Comment: But what if, in the meanwhile some change have been pushed to the remote repo? It is a hard over-write then?

Comment: Yeah. Thats the only way i think. And also you should compare the changes carefully before push it to repo. Anyway, working with `git`, you ideally commit often in small changes, so the changes will easy to track and inspect. You should've push it to repo before you re-install your computer dude.

Comment: Another option for backup is create a `zip` or `rar` archive. So the `.git` folder is still in there.

Comment: great! That'll work fine anyway! Thx for your help

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitHub to host your repo then just clone the latest version of the code by running the "git clone {repo url}" command.

Best way of finding your repo url is logging into your github account and finding the repository.

Comment: my files on my local folder a probably (at least some of them) more up-to-date than the ones on the remote repo.

Comment: in that case you should probably just do a git init and add a remote 
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/